# How to print url arguments in headers view

Tags: views

I have a View and inside it I have and Attachment display. In this attachment I set a Header where I need to print the 2nd url argument. How can I do this? With globals?
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php print arg(1); ?>
```

See: [`arg`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7)

Arg can be used to get the url arguments. It's 0 indexed, so 0 will give the first url argument.

Notice, when using url aliases that arg will bring the internal url arguments (the original path).